# Is there any CSS minifier in C / C++ / Perl for Linux / Mac ?

Tags: css

Can you point me to a **CSS minifier** written in **C or C++ or Perl** so that I can use it on linux / Mac ?

Answer (score 4):

Another very useful software for compress css, among other niceties is Less: http://lesscss.org/

```
$ lessc -x styles.less > styles.css
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use Ruby but there are some nice online minifiers that might fit the bill:

http://www.minifycss.com/css-compressor/

http://refresh-sf.com/yui/

Or you could pull this Perl implementation from CPAN (looks like very young software though):

[http://metacpan.org/pod/CSS::Minifier](http://metacpan.org/pod/CSS%3a%3aMinifier)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSSTidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/), it minimizes CSS files and written in C++ (also have PHP version).

Answer (score -2):

**[Code Beautifier](http://www.codebeautifier.com/)** is the best I have come across - plenty of options and all online so platform independent.

Comment: Does not directly answer his question (he explicitly asked for a minifier that he could use on his operating system), therefore the -1.